# How do I call a function from another scene?

Tags: swift, skscene

My game unlocks a level every-time they beat a level. So the problem im having is when the user beats level one I want it to show a button of level 2 thats in my GameScene. When I call the function unlockLevelTwo() in my Level1.swift file it doesn't show up in my GameScene.swift file. What am I doing wrong?

```
//GameScene.Swift

func unlockLevelTwo() {

    let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeInWithDuration(0.5)

    levelTwo.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2.0, self.size.height / 2.2)
    levelTwo.zPosition = 20
    levelTwo.setScale(0.8)
    levelTwo.alpha = 0
    levelTwo.runAction(fadeIn)
    levelTwo.name = "leveltwo"
    addChild(levelTwo)
}


//Level1.swift

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && sixthBody.categoryBitMask == GoldKeyCategory{

       //calling this function from my gameScene to unlock levelTwo button.

        var gameScene = GameScene()
        gameScene.unlockLevelTwo()

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function:

```
if firstBody.categoryBitMask == HeroCategory && sixthBody.categoryBitMask == GoldKeyCategory{

       //calling this function from my gameScene to unlock levelTwo button.

        var gameScene = GameScene()
        gameScene.unlockLevelTwo()

    }
```

is creating a new `GameScene` object and adding the childNode "levelTwo" to that gamescene.  Instead, you need to call `unlockLevelTwo()` on the actual `GameScene` that is currently presented to the user.

I imagine somewhere in Level1.Swift there is a reference to the current `GameScene` (the one the user is interacting with)? Call the function on that one.

EDIT:

In essence, what you must do is keep a reference to your original `GameScene` object somewhere in your code, which I will henceforth refer to it as `MyScene`.  That way, when in Level1.swift, you can reference `MyScene` and add buttons, levels, whatever you like to it without creating a new one like you did here:

`var gameScene = GameScene()
gameScene.unlockLevelTwo()`

Instead, you would just call

`MyScene.unlockLevelTwo()`.

If `Level1` is a view of some sort, or an object that gets created, in the `init` function you could pass in your `GameScene` object and set it like so

```
class Level1 : (Type) {
    var myScene: GameScene!

    init(myScene: GameScene) {
        self.myScene = myScene)
    }
}
```

Something like that, hope it helps!

Comment: I dont understand what your trying to say. Do you want me to call just the unlockLevelTwo() function by its self?

Comment: So when you use these two lines of code: `var gameScene = GameScene() and gameScene.unlockLevelTwo()`, you are creating a completely new `GameScene` object and then telling _that_ `GameScene` object to unlock level two.  But the user can't see that `GameScene` because you haven't presented it (I imagine somewhere in your code you have a function called `presentScene('your scene here')`. _That_ is the scene the User is currently interacting with.  You must call `unlockLevelTwo` on that scene, not a newly created one, does that make sense?

Comment: Sorry, it's a bit confusing to write up, but essentially what's happening is the the user is seeing `GameScene A` and this function is creating a `GameScene B` and calling `unlockLevelTwo()` on `GameScene B`.  But you/the user can only see `GameScene A` and thus it appears to not work properly.

Comment: I have  the presentScene func in the GameViewController. Is that where I should call the unlockLevelTwo() func? Sorry if Im being difficult I just want to get this to work.

Comment: I'm going to edit my original answer with a bit more information.